# How change Displayname value at runtime based on other parameter value in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[DisplayName("Planned Amt($):")]  
 public string PlannedAmount { get; set; } 
 [DisplayName("Unallocated Amt($):")] 
 public string UnallocatedAmount { get; set; }
```

I have this members in my class .Based on budgetType variable value i need to change the DisplayName Value for both the attributes. Please, let me know how to do that.

Comment: I've added a 'Hi!' at the beggining and a 'Please' at the end of your question. To be polite is free.

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to inherit from DisplayNameAttribute and override the DisplayName property:

```
public class DisplayNameExAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            // do what you want here.
            return base.DisplayName;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't actually tried to implement this, so it is possible that the DisplayName attribute is coded such that some other extension point will have to be used, but I'll try to confirm.

Comment: I am trying to implement your idea, but I need to see the value of the other properties in the class - any ideas? I have logged my own question here if it's better to reply there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669627/custom-display-name-in-mvc-view-model#56669627  If I override the validation attribute I can access other property values, but cannot figure out how to do it for display attributes

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit from DisplayNameAttribute like this:

```
public class BudgetDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public BudgetDisplayNameAttribute(string pBaseName) : base(pBaseName) { }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return My.BudgetType + " " + base.DisplayName;
        }
    }
}
```

Where, for this example, My.BudgetType is a public static string in a public static class:

```
public static class My
{
    public static string BudgetType = "Quarterly";
}
```

And then apply the attribute to your property like this:

```
[BudgetDisplayName("Planned Amt($):")]  
public string PlannedAmount { get; set; } 
[BudgetDisplayName("Unallocated Amt($):")] 
public string UnallocatedAmount { get; set; }
```

Finally, the part of your program that uses the DisplayName attribute of your properties will get the text:

**"Quarterly Planned Amt($):" for the PlannedAmount property**

**"Quarterly Unallocated Amt($):" for the UnallocatedAmount property**