# Custom Display Name in MVC view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC ViewModel class (highly simplified example here) where I'd like LabelFor and ValidationFor to pick up a custom display name. It is a user defined name, so I don't want to use a hard coded name, and I cannot use localization either as the display name is being returned to me in the JSON that the view model is being deserialized from.

I'd like to do something along these lines:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("UserField1Name")]
    public string UserField1 { get; set; }

    public string UserField1Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("UserField2Name")]
    public string UserField2 { get; set; }

    public string UserField2Name { get; set; }
}
```

But the current example just labels the field as UserField1Name, and does not pick up the value of that property by that same name.

Is there any way to do this via the view model?

Comment: @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.UserField1 )

Comment: DisplayName just gives you a custom name for display only.  it doesn't remap one property to another.

Comment: Tony is right, I have just tested and I just see "ExtraDetails1Name", not the value of that property, Amine's suggestion does not work

Comment: I don't mind writing my own Attribute if there is no way of doing it already. It doesn't seem to be possible though. In custom validators you get access to the context, and can get the class's other propertyvalues from that, but I cannot see anything exposed in the attributes class that does anything similar

Answer (score 0):

You can use an overload of `LabelFor` instead of the `DisplayName` attribute:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserField2, Model.UserField2Name)
```

Comment: That sorts out the LabelFor() problem, but not the ValidationFor() or the validation summary, that still refers to "UserField1Name is required", or "UserField1Name is too long", etc. That's why I;m trying to do this via the model attributes so that the effect carries through everywhere